# Opening files in directory, storing read values in lowercase list python

Tags: python-3.x, file, for-loop

I have a folder with txt files that I am trying to append so that all contents are converted to lowercase values (I also want to do some further analysis, but that's a problem for another day).

What I tried to do was create an empty lis, then populate that list with the read contents from the files that were opened in a loop, and finally use list.lower() to convert all values in the list to lowercase.

I haven't got any error messages, but this code clearly isn't working.

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir('.')
#Create empty list to store file contents
Lcase_content = []

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join('.', filename)) as file:
            content = file.read()   
            Lcase_content = content.lower()
            print(Lcase_content)
```

Ideally the list called Lcase_content has all lowercase terms for the content in each file that is being opened.

There is no output when I print, as the list Lcase is empty (and some reason is shown as a str type variable instead of list type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `Lcase_content = []` as a list. But then you redefine/overwrite it `Lcase_content = content.lower()` as String

Instead use `Lcase_content.append(content.lower())`

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir('.')
#Create empty list to store file contents
Lcase_content = []

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join('.', filename)) as file:
            content = file.read()   
            Lcase_content.append(content.lower())
print(Lcase_content)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's finally giving me something - although the contents of the array are just empty values: ['', '', '', ''] - any idea why that is?

Comment: I used print(content), but it doesn't output anything, so I'm assuming there's an error from the with open(os.path...) line, but can't quite figure out what..

Comment: Try printing out the whoile path `print(os.path.join('.', filename))` to check that you are reading the right files. Also check that your `.txt` files are not emty.

Comment: Yes, so that's confusing. I tried printing the path and it's coming out fine. I am a COMPLETE idiot. I just checked the text files, and they are empty.. I must have deleted the contents without realising. Should I delete my account now? Thanks so much for your help! haha